# Ajax loaded page issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a page in which when a button is clicked
a new page is loaded with ajax 
when button is clicked again old page will load via ajax

new page has many jquery functions
my problem is 
when 3 or more times these button is clicked 
jquery events are repeating

for ex

if in new page a delete button is there and has a script which will give a confirm  prompt to delete

then if main button was clicked many times(for ex 3 times new page is loaded)

when i click delete button now 3 times confirm will load  and function will execute 3 times

i can solve this if i placed only script in another part which is not loaded by ajax
with help of 'on()'  functions

but here i cannot do that

so is there any way to solve this by clearing previous loaded cache or something like that?

Comment: why don't check or flag if the new page has been clicked or not, if yes don't load it again.

Comment: @Kyojimaru if i use a flag i have to use on() function in present script. i dont want to use on()

Comment: what script that you're using now then to detect click on button then load new page from ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Only way you can do is

if its jquery
use off function before on function
http://api.jquery.com/off/

if its normal javascript
use removeevent listener
[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)